# Mysql change column data type from integer to double without loosing old data

Tags: mysql

I have a column BEDS in a table and its type is int(11) now there is a requirement where I need to change it to double where it can take decimal values too.
   Here is the code I can use:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY BEDS double;
```

But here I am just worried like am I going to loose data which is already exists?
If so then what is the alternative I can do update with out affecting the existing data?

Comment: Changing `int` to `double` seems very odd to me (because first type is fixed and precise while second is not). Are you sure you don't wont to use `decimal`? And - no, there will be no data loosing

Comment: Nothing to worry. Because you will not loose any data while altering from int to double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can create a new field in your table `BEDS_double` then copy the data from your existing field over into your new field:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET BEDS_double = BEDS;
```

But there is no real need to do this. If you change your field's type from `int` to `double` you will not lose any data. On the other hand if you convert from `double` to `int` you may lose your precision and your data may be affected by rounding.